# Automate iis backup

Tags: windows, backup, iis-6

I would like to automate the backup of ISS metabase. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a scheduled task pointing to a batch file with the following inside (IIS7):

appcmd add backup <--backupname-->

Although if setting up and administrating this kind of thing is your day-to-day job then I'd recommend investing in a book on Powershell and doing things properly (i.e. mapping network drives before hand, adding reporting, emailing the admins on failures, incrementing the backupname by date etc.).

Just noticed the ii6 tag on your post, so:

http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-2000/how-can-i-back-up-the-microsoft-iis-metabase-from-the-command-line-in-windows-2000-and-later-.aspx

Luke